# Is there any way of using name of class as a name of usual data type?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, adt

Well, I have two structures (two ADTs) `Cashier` and `Porter` that have common property `salary`. It is reached by implementing class `Worker`.

```
type Money = Int
type Kg = Int

class Worker a where
    salary :: a -> Money

data Cashier = C { salaryC :: Money 
                 , polite :: Bool
                 }

instance Worker Cashier where
    salary = salaryC

data Porter = P { salaryP :: Money
                , liftingForce :: Kg
                }

instance Worker Porter where
    salary = salaryP
```

Common iterface means common action. This gives me ability not to write two different variations of any function that uses common property of the given ADTs.

For example:

```
hasSalary :: (Worker a) => a -> Bool
hasSalary x = (salary x) > 0
```

But when I try to declare another type such as `data Stuff = S [Worker]`  compilator won't let me do this way.

Won't of course work also `type Stuff = [(Worker a) => a]` or `(Worker a) => type Stuff = [a]`

Yes, there is datatype-constructor:

```
data (Worker a) => Stuff a = S [a]
```

and even GADT's version:

```
data Stuff a where
    S :: Worker a => [a] -> Stuff [a]
```

but it is not the thing I really want. Because every time I work with `Stuff` there will be difference between `Stuff Cashier` and `Stuff Porter`.

**So is there any variant of using class' name `Worker` as a type of field in structure like it was a usual data type (`Int` for example)?**

Comment: There will always be a difference between `Stuff Cashier` and `Stuff Porter`, since `Cashier` and `Porter` are distinct and unrelated types. `Worker` is not a class in the popular object-oriented sense, if that's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Don't use anything from this answer before you've also read [this piece of mandatory reading](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).*

---

If I understood the question correctly (or, *guessed* really, it is rather unclear), what you are asking for is a *heterogeneous collection*: a list that can contain `Cashier`s and `Porter`s in some arbitrary mix. That's after all what `List<Worker>` would be in a language like Java.

For that,

```
type Stuff = [(Worker a) => a]
```

is the thing you tried that makes sense: the `a` must only appear in the list entries, not in the overall data type (because then they're constrained to be all the same type).

In fact, the attempt *would* work if Haskell had an *existential quantifier*:

```
type Stuff = [∃ a . Worker a => a]
```

Haskell doesn't have that, but it's possible to wrap the existential in a GADT:

```
data AWorker where
  AWorker :: Worker a => a -> AWorker

type Stuff = [AWorker]
```

Comment: I'd add that, given the OP class, `[AWorker]` is isomorphic to `[Money]` (which is the suggested solution in the blog post you linked to).

Comment: There is effort to bring first-class `exists.` into GHC: [An Existential Crisis Resolved: Type inference for first-class existential types](https://richarde.dev/papers/2021/exists/exists.pdf)